# Cluster Shape and Size

Tags: database, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I'd like to ask about how the shape and the size of a cluster is mathematically determined. For example, I have read that K-means clustering algorithm fails to find clusters of non-convex shapes, where it succeeds at finding spherical or convex shaped clusters only. Also, it trys to find clusters with same size. Is this related to its distance similarity function? If yes, what kind of similarity function is good to find non-convex cluster shapes with different sizes? If no, please tell me what factor affects the shape and the size of a cluster.

Also, is probability based similarity function good to find non-convex cluster shapes with different sizes?

Please help me figure out the answer, thanks a lot.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithms don't "define" shape or size.

Much of what you cited ("k-means can only find spherical clusters") is just a rule of thumb, not a mathematical property.

Technically, k-means will partition your data into Voronoi cells. So it is quite easy to see what clusters cannot be found by k-means (for example, voronoi cells are convex). But that is pretty much all you have - if you generate a data set based on Voronoi cells, k-means will fail to recover it. It needs a center of mass in the middle of the cell.

There are also variants such as kernel k-means where it is far from obvious what kinds of clusters it can discover.

k-means *must* not be used with other distances. Don't treat it as distance based, it **minimizes variance**. For other distances, use k-medoids. Kernelized k-means should be safe, it will minimize variance in the projected kernel space, and terminate. With other distances, k-means may fail to converge, because the *mean* only minimizes squared Euclidean (so you would need to replace the mean).

If you want to find other cluster shapes, don't start with k-means. Consider k-means as least-squares-quantization, not as attempt to find clusters of a particular shape (it is not "designed" for spherical clusters of the same size, but it only cares about optimizing the sum-of-squares formula).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer.